# The result of using the closure function

Tags: javascript

[image]
[image]

It looks like you are calling a function and storing the call to that function in a variable.
Why are the outcome different?????

I thought the results would be the same, why are they different?

Comment: Don't post images of code: post code, data and error messages as text. See [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You seem to ignore that when `a` is not a parameter of the `return function()` then a is already replaced with the current value outside the scope. This is a great feature of JS but you need to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `createCount` returns a function object.  So this:

```
console.log(createCount())
```

Just prints the function object.  It does not CALL the function that was returned.  Where as this:

```
count = createCount()
console.log(count())
```

Stores the function object, and then CALLS that function object.  Two very different operations.

It's like the difference between these two:

```
console.log(Math.random);
console.log(Math.random());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some code that makes intuitive sense.

The code above is like

```js
console.log(function() {
    return a += 1 // a = 0 at first
}())
```

The code below is like

```js
console.log(function() {
    let a = 0
    return function() {
       return a += 1
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you indicate this is an example of closures where a function has access to values in the outer scope, as long as they aren't shaded by other functions.

I think this example is a lot simpler to get a first understanding:

```js
function fullName(name){
  const surname = "aerial";
  return (name) => `${name} ${surname}`
}
```

So surname is already replaced.

You could also use other variables form the outer scope like `process.env.SURNAME` in a NodeJS process.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code...

```js
function createCount() 
  {
  let a = 0;
  return function (txt)
    {
    return `${txt} -> ${++a}`
    }
  }  
const 
  countA = createCount()
, countB = createCount()
  ;
console.log( countA('A') );
console.log( countA('A') );
console.log( countA('A') );
console.log( '------' );
console.log( countB('B') );
console.log( countB('B') );
```